# performance about string convert to int

Tags: php, string, performance, int

If i have sting like

```
$str = '515';
```

I want convert it to int, is better use

```
$str = $str * 1;
```

than use

```
$str = intval($str);
```

which performance is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `$str = $str * 1`, `$str` will first cast into an integer then plus 1, so it is one step more.

Besides, `$str = intval($str);` is much more readable than `$str = $str * 1;`,

You could also just use casting by `$str = (int)$str`.

Answer (score 5):

Casting the value using `(int)` should be the quickest option as intval() invokes a function (which has a small performance overhead)

```
$str = (int)$str;
```

see http://wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP#Typecasting for more information